# Hierarchical Database Menu

Tags: mysql, database

I've been looking through posts that talk about selecting hierarchical content from a database, but I still have doubts on how I could implement the following:
I've three tables:

- Locations: Here I store a location and its correspondent parent (e.g Europe->UK->London).
- Buildings: Here I store buildings.  One building must be in one location.
- User-locations:  Here I store the locations that a particular user will be able to see.
- User-Buildings:  Here I store the buildings that a particular user will be able to see.

Note that an admin can say: "User 1 will see all the buildings from Japan, and also he will be able to see that particular building from France, but just that one".

With all that, I would like to build a menu (for a particular user) that will be something like:

- Buildings

  - Europe

    - Germany

      - Munich

        - Building_1
        - Building_2
    - UK

      - London

        - Building_3

I'm having some doubts about how could I get that information, and I would appreciate any thoughts.

Edited:

Table Structure:

1) Buildings

- Id (primary key)
- Name, description,...
- location_ID (foreign key to location table)
- Company_ID (foreign key to the company table.. A building must belong to just one company).

2) Locations

- Id (primary key)
- Name
- Parent Id (foreign key to the table itself.. e.g: London entry would have a foreign key to UK entry.

3) Company

- Id (primary key)
- Name, description...

4) Users

- Id (primary key)
- Company_ID (foreign key to the company of this user (a user belongs just to one company).

5) User-Buildings

- Id_User (Foreign key to user table)
- Id_Building (Foreign key to building table)

6) User-Location

- Id_User (Foreign key to user table)
- Id_Location (Foreign key to location table)

The idea is that a company can assign which buildings a user can see. A company can assign specific buildings (not location dependent) and that's why the existence of the User-Building table, and they can also assign a location, so the user will see all the buildings that belong to that location.

Thanks for the comments, and I hope I've clarified a little bit.

Thanks.

Comment: Regarding storing the hierarchical data in MySql, see http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html

Comment: Can you tell us your table structure and maybe make up some demo data?

This question is just about storing and retrieving data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with your current database schema, the problem is that locations don't seem to have a fixed number of levels, so you will have to do an ugly loop to fetch sublevels of `user_location.id_location` and their buildings.
It would help a lot if you could distinguish location levels in meaningful categories such as region, country, city. That way you could have such a table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE buildings (
    id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ...
    region_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    country_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    city_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX (region_id),
    INDEX (country_id),
    INDEX (city_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (region_id) REFERENCES locations(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES locations(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY (city_id) REFERENCES locations(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
) TYPE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE user_location (
    user_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    location_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, region_id, country_id, city_id),
    INDEX (user_id),
    INDEX (location_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (location_id) REFERENCES locations(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) TYPE=InnoDB;
```

Then you can retrieve your buildings like this:

```
SELECT * FROM buildings WHERE id IN (
    (SELECT building_id FROM user_buildings WHERE user_id = ?)
    UNION
    (SELECT id FROM buildings 
    LEFT JOIN user_location ON 
    (user_location.location_id = buildings.region_id
        OR user_location.location_id = buildings.country_id
        OR user_location.location_id = buildings.city_id)
    WHERE user_id = ?)
);
```

Returned rows will contain the information you need to build your tree.

Comment: Thanks for this Alessando. My only concern is that even if a user is related to different locations, and therefore we can get all the buildings from that location, it can happen that a user has a building and just one building in a location.

Comment: That's supported. My schema allows you do define multiple policies for each user: `user_buildings` contains single-building permissions, while `user_location` contains wider policies that allow the user to see all buildings in a city/country/region. If you want the user to see single buildings without giving them permissions for the entire location, just put a row in `user_buildings`.